# Postman is giving me error "Error: read ECONNRESET"

Tags: java, spring, postman

I wanted to test my new API, but it was giving me error with `Postman`
so i redownloaded it and in the initial page it was a test api : `http://github.com/user/repo/main/db.json`
With GetMethod i just sent there but it is giving me error in console:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
Proxy
id: "f36a2318-be97-400f-b630-26aeb0b38f8e"
disabled: false
host: "121.0.0.1"
match: {…}
port: 8080
tunnel: false
authenticate: false
Request Headers
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 48e66b61-7f3b-4f15-b0c2-f266c066e9ec
Host: github.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

And in response i am getting

```
Could not send request
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND user
```

What i am doing wrong , and why it is giving me error, i just newly donwloaded it:
Here is my Headers:
[it was also automatically there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZwDP.png)

Comment: also i turned off SSL certificate

Comment: Usually means the resource you are requesting isn't found or you are hitting the wrong URL, Check your hostname, endpoint, resource requested, SSL certificate required if any !

Comment: @Harsh 'Not found' would cause HTTP status 404. Not ECONNRESET.

Comment: You can't get both `ECONNRESET` *and* `ENOTFOUND user`. Make up your mind.

Answer (score 0):

In my case(C# + IIS) one property from response was missing a

```
set {}
```

because it was a calculated property( only get{} )

Answer (score 0):

For me - System restart resolved this ECONNRESET issue.